# Different imports do import different class objects in Python?

Tags: python, import

Until now I usually imported modules as

```
from quantumClasses.qcAbstract import QCAbstract
```

where quantumClasses was a folder in the PYTHONPATH route. But if I happened to be in another module in the same path, instead of this I could do

```
from qcAbstract import QCAbstract
```

and it seemed the same and I never paid much attention to which of them I was using. But now I came across a distressing case. I simplified it in the toy example below. Car is a class with a class attribute. I have functions that import it both ways mentioned before, and they seem to be accessing different classes.

Consider files:

```
# car.py

class Car(object):
    attrib = 0


# tools1.py
from car import Car

def get1():
    return Car.attrib

def set1(val):
    Car.attrib = val


# tools2.py
from car import Car

def get2():
    return Car.attrib

def set2(val):
    Car.attrib = val


# tools3.py
from quantumClasses.car import Car

def get3():
    return Car.attrib

def set3(val):
    Car.attrib = val


# testCar.py
from tools1 import get1, set1
from tools2 import get2, set2
from tools3 import get3, set3


set1(10)
set3(5)
print(get1())
print(get3())
print(get2())
```

When I execute testCar.py, I get

```
10
5
10
```

So, it seems that I am handling two different classes quantumClasses.qcAbstract.QCAbstract
and qcAbstract.QCAbstract, although both of them are defined in the same physical file.

Am I doing something wrong? What is the standard way to avoid these awkward situations?

EDIT: Should have specified, this is Python 2.7

Comment: This is python 2.6? That's a side effect of relative paths AFAIK - you can use absolute imports to get around it (which may break other things) iirc. I think Python 3+ does not have this problem, and python 2.7 may not either (migrating now, not quite there).

Comment: @CorleyBrigman Good point, it is Python2.7, I just clarified it in the question.

Comment: I know this is already answered. That is a solution, but a better solution is to move to absolute imports. See PEP 328: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-relative-imports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you import the same file as two different modules.
They have two different names.

Look into `sys.modules`. `car.__name__` and `quantumClasses.car.__name__` should be different.

This is because you import them from two different paths, maybe `site-packages` and `.`. This way Python can not determine wether it is the same file. since the one file is `site-packages/quantumClasses/car.py` and the other is `./car.py`.

If you want to set the names as the some do

1. decide for one import! usually this would be `quantumClasses.car`
2. possible but meta and not recommended: `import sys; sys.modules['quantumClasses.car'] = car`

Comment: Thanks, I will take option 1, the other seems really ugly.